# using sleep(), I cannot get my values to echo

Tags: php

I'm using a sleep function inside of a foreach loop and I'd like to echo the value inside the loop. Why isn't this working? The $test var inside the loop never changes from 0.

```
foreach($test as $val){
 ob_start();
 echo $test++;
 sleep(1);
 ob_end_flush();
}
```

Comment: If it's so bad, hows come you can't answer it smart guy?  :)

Comment: What does foreach ($test as $val) {$test++} do? Nothing interesting as far as I can tell. What did $test start as before the foreach? Or perhaps, what does ++ do to an array?

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
foreach ($test as $val)
{
    ob_start();

    echo $val++;

    sleep(1);

    while (ob_get_level() > 0)
    {
        ob_end_flush();
    }

    flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flush after each echo, instead of using output buffering.

Comment: Ignacio, I tried flush and got nothing. The same thing happens. I try to echo anything inside the loop and it just hangs.